# Finding the correct selector for: add div to parent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="dropdownedit">
<div class="dropbtn">textxyz</div>
<div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;">
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text1">text1</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text2">text2</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text3">text3</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text4">text4</div>
</div></div>
```

now I would like to add a new div line `<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text0">text0</div>`

to the dropdown-content class. This should be done WITHIN a on-click-event (`$("#table_cards").on( 'click', 'div.ocond', function (e) {...`) of the class "ocond" (inside of the dropdown-content class).

I have tried those two options:

```
$(this).closest('.dropdown-content').prepend('<div ... >text0</div>');
```

and

```
$(this).parent('.dropdown-content').prepend('<div ... >text0</div>');
```

but both do not work.I can not find the correct selector for making this happen when clicking on the "ocond" class.
Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: How did you define the `click` event?

Comment: $("#table_cards").on( 'click', 'div.ocond', function (e) {

Comment: Try `$(e.target)` instead of `$(this)`

Comment: $(.dropdown-content).prepend() is not an option due to the fact that there are houndreds of dropdown-content divs ...

Comment: tried it ... not working :(

Comment: It is working: _http://jsfiddle.net/nbdvj5a2/_

Comment: Did you check the fiddle link in the previous comment?

Comment: working now! great! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.parent()` doesn't accept selectors because it simply goes up one level.

`.parents()` does because it keeps going up through the parents, grandparents, etc and will only affect those elements that match the selector.

`.closest()` accepts a selector just like `.parents()` but will stop after finding the first parent to meet the selector.

**You can use `.parent().prepend()`, or `.closest(".dropdown-content").prepend()`**

```js
$(".dropbtn").click( function() { 
  $(this).nextAll(".dropdown-content").first().show();
});

$(".dropdownedit").mouseleave( function() { 
  $(this).find(".dropdown-content").hide();
});

$(".ocond").click( function() { 
  $(this).closest('.dropdown-content').prepend("<div href='#' class='ocond' id='text0'>text0</div>");
  $(this).closest('.dropdown-content').hide(); 
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdownedit">
  <div class="dropbtn">textxyz</div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text1">text1</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text2">text2</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text3">text3</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text4">text4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but "$(this).closest('.dropdown-content').prepend(" is not working like I mentioned in my post ... I already tried it

Comment: Maybe you had a typo when you tried it? I've updated my answer to use `.closest(...)` instead of `.parent()` and the snippet is working.